# How to tell apart by Web Api which method to use to return data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am new to asp.net Web Api. I create a simple Web Api App with a `ValuesController`

What will I get when I make a request :

```
api/values/5
```

when there are:

```
public string Get(int id) { }
public void Delete(int id) { }
```

methods in the controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace my2ndWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the HTTP Verb used when making the request.

A `GET` request to `api/values/5` will match `public string Get(int id)`

A `DELETE` request to `api/values/5` will match  `public void Delete(int id)`.

It is actually indicated in the comments of the sample code provided in the original question.

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)